# PhoneGap nested executeSql not working in iPad Emulator

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, sqlite, cordova

Somehow my application works perfectly in Win-Safari, but somehow not when wrapped by PhoneGap. This is the snippet:

```
// working db connection
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tbl', [], function(tx, rs){
    // do something with the result

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM another_tbl', [], function(txTwo, rsTwo){
      // do something with the result

      // further nesting ...

    }, errorHandler, successHandler);

  }, errorHandler, successHandler);
}
```

The first resultSet is correct and I can console.log() the data. But after that, I am not able to access the data of the second nested query.

I don't get any errors and non of my handlers are called (e.g. errorHandler). The funny thing is, that it does not cause any problems on Safari (Win 7)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem.  I have gotten it working by nesting another transaction inside the callback for the first call to executeSql (which I think is terribly ugly, but so be it).

```
context.db.db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT coalesce(sum(pointsawarded),0) as points from eventhistory ", [], function(tx, res) {
        alert('h1' + JSON.stringify(res));
        context.db.db.transaction(function(txsafe) {
            txsafe.executeSql("SELECT coalesce(sum(pointsawarded),0) as points2 from eventhistory ", [], function(tx2, res2) {
                alert('h2' + JSON.stringify(res2));
            });
         });
     });
});
```